# How to remove the movement of Rigid Body elements?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I need to make an animation in which an object crawls out of the ground. To do this, I used Cell Fracture + Rigid Body. But the problem is that the elements of the ground move even if you don't act on them. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Rigid Body elements movements]

Answer (score 1):

There is a little checkmark called **Dynamic** below the mass, and by clicking that, you can enable or disable the state of it moving. It can also be keyframed so you can activate it when needed. Hope this was helpful!

[image]